# Installing MongoDB 4.2 Community Edition on macOS Big Sur

Tags: mongodb, macos

I am trying to install MongoDB 4.2 Community Edition to macOS Big Sur version 11.4 and I am running into error.
What I have done so far:

1. Updated XCode terminal commands
2. Tried to duplicate terminal to create a "Rosetta-Terminal" but that did not work because the Rosetta option would not appear.

I am trying to reinstall MongoDB and I am running into errors.

Tab from first terminal

```
  /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community@4.2/4.2.12: 21 files, 306.6MB, built in 4 seconds
kristianablake@macbook-pro ~ % export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mongodb-community@4.2/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
quote> mongo
quote> mongod
quote> brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community@4.2
quote> 
kristianablake@macbook-pro ~ % brew services start mongodb-community@4.2
==> Successfully started `mongodb-community@4.2` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community@4.2)
kristianablake@macbook-pro ~ % brew services list
Name                  Status  User           Plist
mongodb-community@4.2 started kristianablake /Users/kristianablake/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community@4.2.plist
```

The problem is when I go on a new terminal and type "mongo" the terminal returns "command not found: mongo"

Text from Terminal:

```
kristianablake@macbook-pro ~ % mongo
zsh: command not found: mongo
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: It says "successfully started", what is your problem?

Comment: My apologies, I will fix that. When I go into a new terminal and enter 'mongo' it returns "command not found"

Comment: The mongo shell should be included in the server package. `mongo` should be found by `PATH` variable (or however it is called on MacOS). Did you follow https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

Comment: I restarted the computer, reinstalled the latest mongodb 5.0 version. After going into a new tab and typing "mongo" I miraculously connected to the 4.2.12 server. Thank you for responding!